# How to increase a visitor session duration in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs, analytics

I'm pretty new to PhantomJS, but now I'm testing my web-page+page_analytics. My code can: visit the website and create a .png screenshot. After that, I look at web-page analytics and see: 1 user, but the average session duration is 0:0:0 sec. How to make PhantomJS visit my page and stay on the page for couple a seconds or minutes? I must add cookies or something?
Code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Opera/12.02 (Android 4.1; Linux; Opera Mobi/ADR-1111101157; U; en-US) Presto/2.9.201 Version/12.02';
page.open('http://****.blogspot.com/', function() {

  page.render('k5.png'); 
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Maybe I need to add hits on page? One hit on page in the start of the script and second one when script ends?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait a set time before you take the screenshot have you tried putting a `setTimout` in? Possibly something like this off the top of my head. (Set at 5 Seconds but you can increase that!)

```
setTimeout(function() {
    page.render('k5.png'); 
    phantom.exit();
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Find out about setTImeout here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: I'm trying this code before - and have 0 seconds in analytics =(

Answer (score 0):

For increase a visitor session duration with PhantomJS you must know how Google Analytics works (Google Analytics and almost all other similar tools).
Those tools place a cookie when you visit your first page on the site. When you move from this page to a second page they read the time of yuor first page's visit on the cookie and they calculate the difference between this time and the current time.

Note that you visit only a page on a site this visit will shows 00:00:00 on the report.

For do what your're asking you need to read and save the cookies from your first page visit with PhantomJS and then add them before visit the second page.
For increment the lenght of a session you need instead to do a `setTimeout` between `page.open` and the rendering of the page.

Unfortunately I've done all this stuff with [PHP PhantomJS](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/) so I can't help you with coding it.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively if you are using > Phantom 1.2 this should also work and is a nicer solution.

```
var page = new WebPage(); 
page.open('http://****.blogspot.com/'); 
page.onLoadFinished = function(status) { 
    page.render('k5.png'); 
    phantom.exit(); 
};
```

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html

Comment: Yes, I'm using the newest one! Will try this code right now

Comment: but I don't understand, where I can variate the time that script will stay on site and emulate session duration=(

Comment: where in your current script do you have anything which emulates session duration currently?

Comment: Nowhere, that's why I'm asking about that. You give me this code and I don't understand where it emulates the "time user spends on the page"

Comment: Ah ok sorry I mis-understood and thought you needed to delay the page so you took the screenshot later. Why is it important that your average session duration displays more than 0:0:0? If you pump up the setTimeout before you call the `phantom.exit()` does that not show anything?

Comment: Yes, It's still shows 00:00:00. It's important for me because in the future I want to test this script on my application that hosted on my own computer, And I want to know how much online users my app and computer can handle at once.